# How to generate graphs and statistics from SQLAlchemy tables?

Tags: python, matplotlib, sqlalchemy

After running a bunch of simulations I'm going to be outputting the results into a table created using SQLAlchemy. I plan to use this data to generate statistics - mean and variance being key. These, in turn, will be used to generate some graphs - histograms/line graphs, pie-charts and box-and-whisker plots specifically.

I'm aware of the Python graphing libraries like `matplotlib`. The thing is, I'm not sure how to have this integrate with the information contained within the database tables.

Any suggestions on how to make these two play with each other?

The main problem is that I'm not sure how to supply the information as "data sets" to the graphing library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like matplotlib takes simple python data types -- lists of numbers, etc, so you'll be need to write custom code to massage what you pull out of mysql/sqlalchemy for input into the graphing functions...

Comment: Are you aware of any other data types it can handle? I suppose dictionaries would be most useful data structure for my purposes.

Comment: I guess, reading the API documentation (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/contents.html) would be helpful. The other good way is to go through the examples and see what daty types are passed to those charting functions you will use (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/index.html).